# How do I make exclamation marks show using echo

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Earlier today, I was continuing on making an RAR Password Decryptor. I was testing it out on a test RAR file with the password being just an exclamation mark but when I use my Decryptor all it says is just "Echo has been turned off". The bug is located at the bottom of the coding next to where it says "echo".

This is the coding for the RAR Password Decryptor that I've done so far (and if it's okay can you tell me any more bugs and give me some tips thanks people).

```
REM ============================================================
REM errorcode401.blogspot.in
@echo off
title Decryptor
mode con: cols=50 lines=50
copy "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Unrar.exe"
SET PSWD=0
SET DEST=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%
MD %DEST%
:RAR
cls
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo                   GET DETAIL
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo.
SET/P "NAME=Enter File Name : "
IF "%NAME%"=="" goto NERROR
goto GPATH
:NERROR
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo                      ERROR
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo Sorry you can't leave the line blank.
pause
goto RAR
:GPATH
SET/P "PATH=Enter Full Path : "
IF "%PATH%" == "" goto PERROR
goto NEXT
:PERROR
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo                      ERROR
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo Sorry you can't leave the line blank.
pause
goto RAR
:NEXT
IF EXIST "%PATH%\%NAME%" GOTO START
goto PATH
:PATH
cls
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo                     ERROR
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo This file does not Exist.
pause
goto RAR
:START
SET /A PSWD=%PSWD%+1
echo 1q2w!3e
UNRAR E -INUL -P%PSWD% "%PATH%\%NAME%" "%DEST%"
IF /I %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO FINISH
GOTO START
:FINISH
RD %DEST% /Q /S
Del "Unrar.exe"
cls
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo                     CRACKED
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo.
echo PASSWORD FOUND!
echo FILE  = %NAME%
echo CRACKED PASSWORD = %PSWD%
pause>NUL
exit
REM ===========================
```

Comment: Oh 18th last line my apologies. XD

Comment: Also the problem is how can I make exclamation marks be viewed in echo because the exclamation marks turns echo off when I want the exclamation marks to be seen (echo on) instead of being a code.

Comment: Oh wow lol what is wrong with me I ment exclamation mark not a quotation mark lol my apologies again. XD

Comment: `echo 1q2w!3e` outputs `1q2w!3e`. Please explain what the **real problem is**

Comment: OK, you know that your question has problems.  You wave your hands and say "the bug is in the code" without saying where.  You use the wrong name for the character you're talking about.  You're reporting a problem that we can't reproduce.  Stop tacking on comments, and *fix* your questing by [edit]ing it.  Also, if you have a problem in one line, you shouldn't need to post 68 lines.  Try editing your batch file.  Delete big chunks.  If the problem persists, post a *short* script that has the problem.  If the problem goes away, the last code you deleted may have been the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 8):

If you are having problems `echo`ing `!` then you have [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) set.

If [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is set, then `!` is treated as a special character and **must be escaped** with `^`.

`^` must be used twice as it is also a special character.

> **Escaping Exclamation marks**
>
> When the shell is running in EnableDelayedExpansion mode the !
>   character is used to denote a variable and so it must be escaped (twice)
>   if you wish to treat it as a regular character, you should do this:
>
> `^^!`

---

Without `EnableDelayedExpansion`:

```
@echo off
echo 1q2w!3e
```

Output:

```
1q2w!3e
```

---

With `EnableDelayedExpansion` **and no escaping**:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo 1q2w!3e
```

Output:

```
1q2w3e
```

Notice the **missing** `!` in the output.

---

With `EnableDelayedExpansion` **and escaping**:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo 1q2w^^!3e
```

Output:

```
1q2w!3e
```

---

[EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) can be set in three ways:

- Using `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` in a batch file
- Starting `cmd` with the `/v` switch.
- In the registry under `HKLM` or `HKCU`

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"DelayedExpansion"= (REG_DWORD)
1=enabled 0=disabled (default)
```

---

Sources [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)